Matched geometry effect one way
I'm using matched geometry effect to animate selection of an item and it works nicely but I'm having an issue that I only want it to animate one way when selecting. It's a bit hard to explain visually so I've uploaded a movie with the current result.

As you can see in the movie, when I select an item it animates nicely into the box but also there's an animation when it disappears which I don't want to have.
I'm using just the vanilla modifier like this:
.matchedGeometryEffect(id: id, in: namespace)

Please show a [mcve].

Thanks @Sweeper when making an RPE I noticed that it indeed does work. The issue seemed to be that the item was not removed from the array when selected properly.

The issue seemed to be that the item was not removed from the array when selected properly.
